# known iOS mail bug? The inbox skips over displaying hundreds of messages (IF inbox has >500 messages or so)

Tags: ios, mail.app

I would like to know if others see this bug, or if it is known -- in other words, if it is just me. If it is a universal bug, it is a big one in my opinion.

My iOS mail app is showing a bug in two mail accounts that I have whose inboxes had more than 500-600 emails in them. When I view the inboxes for those two accounts, the app omits a huge segment of the emails that are actually indeed in those inboxes. Basically skipping over a few years of emails. (When I view those accounts over in my mail app on my mac, or go to those directly on webmail, those mails are nicely there.)

When I later moved emails around so that less than 400-500 emails were in the inbox, the mail app stopped showing that glaring skipping and things appeared in correct order.

How the bug behaved for me (before I moved emails to limit the number in a folder):

-- On one of the mail accounts, the very top of the inbox showed 40 or 50 recent emails correctly. But then, at a certain point, the emails skipped from 2012 all the way back to 2007, and continue backwards from there!  (That email account is a regular IMAP account. Provider is Fastmail, but as you see below, the problem is also seen on a Yahoo account too.)

-- On the other mail account, a Yahoo account, the very top of the inbox showed about 25 recent emails correctly. Then below that it suddenly cut all the way back to 2001.

-- This same bug also happens on two iOS devices: my iPad and my iPod touch.

-- Again, the bug does not happen on the Mail app on my mac OS laptop.  It deals just fine and correctly.

-- Things I tried that did not fix the bug prior to simply drastically limiting number of emails:
* removed the email account from the iOS device and then re-configuring it again: problem was still there.
* totally reinstalling the entire iOS system, restoring from the auto backup: problem was still there.

Again, I just want to know if this bug is universal for all.  Got any large folders with, say, 1000 mails in them?  Do you see this huge message skippage if you scroll down in the inbox several pages?

Comment: This happens to me when I view my emails in the "All Inboxes" section of the iOS Mail app.

Comment: aha...  my first guess would be that that choice of 'all inboxes' takes the number of emails over the same "too much" amount that is causing the bug for me.    To me this is a big bug... I mean, a lot of us have folders or inboxes with more than 500-600 emails, right?  I keep all old email, and I don't painstakingly subcategorize them. Hope this gets fixed!!